# Pulling data into email from multiple data extensions

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, ampscript, dataextensions

I am receiving the below errors when trying to test send an email that has personalization strings from two different data extensions that are imported into Marketing Cloud.

> The subscriber preview failed to generate. Review the details, correct
>   all issues, and try again. Personalization error: The personalization
>   string "" was not found in the following data extension(s).  To fix
>   the problem, please try the following:
>    - Make sure that there is not a space or typo within the personalization string in your email. For example, check and correct
>   any spaces between percent signs (%%)
>    - Verify that the field containing the personalization string value is in all data extensions used.
>    - Correct the Subject of your email. HTML Version Personalization error: The personalization string "" was not found in the following
>   data extension(s).  To fix the problem, please try the following:
>    - Make sure that there is not a space or typo within the personalization string in your email. For example, check and correct
>   any spaces between percent signs (%%)
>    - Verify that the field containing the personalization string value is in all data extensions used.
>    - Correct the HTML Body of your email.

Another email's personalization strings are populating just fine, but these attributes are coming from a sales cloud extension.

DE 1 = "Customers" - includes First Name attribute
DE 2 = "Contacts" - includes Referral Code attribute

I have the `%%firstname%%` in the subject line and `%%referralcode%%` in the body (to reference each of the errors). I have checked to make sure that there are no spaces in the HTML.

The email audience was created from a filtered data extension via the two DE referenced above, that have a data relationship connected by a "contact ID".

I have been reading that I should try AMPscript when trying to pull in data from two DE, but am really confused on how to get started with that. I have been told that the email can pull data from other DE other than the one I am sending to, but it doesn't seem to be working for me. I attempted also to try using a lookup code, but that failed as well. I am wanting the email to populate each audience member's unique first name and referral code in the email (so i think if i did lookup it would have to include multiple rows..)?

Comment: There's [a brief 4-part series on getting started with AMPscript](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/getStarted-AMPscript.htm) in the online developer documentation that’s worth a look. It starts with the basics and by the end you'll have written code that pulls content from a data extension and loops through multiple rows to personalize an email.

Comment: Thanks @MarkG! I did look through that before and it still seems very confusing.... I'll keep at it though.

Answer (score 2):

'[Personalization strings](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_personalization_strings.htm&type=5)' can only be leveraged from the sending DE. If you want to use a field from another DE you would need to do a `lookup()` function. Detailed in the dev docs: '[Lookup Function](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/lookup.htm)'

You could use this inline within the email like
`%%=lookup('Contacts','referralcode','subscriberkey',_subscrberkey)=%%`

Comment: Thanks @eazye!!! I'm now getting this error....

Comment: The subscriber preview failed to generate. Review the details, correct all issues, and try again.
An error occurred when attempting to resolve a function call. See inner exception for detail.
 Function Call: lookup('ADS_Customer','referralcode','contactid',contactid)
 Index: 1673
 Content Type: Text
 Substitution Level: Subscriber
 Message Context: Preview
The Data Extension name for a Lookup function call is invalid. A Data Extension of this name does not exist.
 Data Extension Name: ADS_Customer

Comment: Function Call: lookup('ADS_Customer','referralcode','contactid',contactid)
 Parameter Name: DataExtensionName
 Parameter Ordinal: 1

Comment: is your de named 'ADS_Customer' is it a shared de?

Comment: How can I determine this?

Comment: is it in the shared DE folder?

Comment: i don't see a "shared" DE folder... i see "Synchronized DE" and then just DE and salesforce DE

Comment: I do see the data extensions though - they are in "active extensions"